# How can I purge just images in cache directory?

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching

I want to clear all images in default cache directory every 1 minute but the cache files do not have extensions to specific their type and I don't know how to delete just images like PNG (not other data).
this is sample code I saw on this site:

```
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
    let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path

    do {
        if let documentPath = documentsPath
        {
            let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(documentPath)")
            print("all files in cache: \(fileNames)")
            for fileName in fileNames {

                if (fileName.hasSuffix(".png"))
                {
                    let filePathName = "\(documentPath)/\(fileName)"
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePathName)
                }
            }

            let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(documentPath)")
            print("all files in cache after deleting images: \(files)")
        }

    } catch {
        print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## possibility:

you could use ImageIO to test EVERY file before deleting it but that would mean reading it before removing it. It'd replace testing for a suffix BUT

as it'd be really unnecessarily expensive IMHO I wont even provide code.

## okay way:

=> Rename your images to have a suffix or prefix so you can identify them by name (n calls)

## good way

=> put the images in a seperate folder and just remove the folder to purge them. (1 call)

Comment: How can I rename images that are going to cache by default cache system?

Comment: If I put them in a separate folder could iOS delete them if memory warning occur? or I should handle them manually?

Comment: what is cache except for images in default cache folder in ios? Is there anything else?